# How to add big file to linux livecd

Tags: linux, livecd

I have a linux live-cd linux.iso(600Mb), two files foo.sh(1Kb) and foo.img(1.3 Gb). How to add files to live-cd and create live-dvd?

Comment: Could you please tell us which operating system you are using currently? The solutions are quite different depending on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give a lot of information, so I'm going to give a couple tips (assuming this is being done under an existing Linux system - if not, then somebody else should answer with Win32 ideas):

1. Programs like `ISO Master` will allow you to directly edit an ISO image and re-export it. They don't burn the image on their own, however.
2. If these are just files, it would be a good idea to make a new directory in the ISO image (using an ISO editor) called `local`, where you can easily find things later.
3. Programs like `Brasero` and `k3b` let you burn the edited ISO to a DVD.
4. To access the files from the LiveCD, you should just be able to `mount` the CD and view the `local` directory. Most file managers will automount this for you, if the live distro doesn't do it on its own. It can usually be found somewhere in `/mnt` or `/mount`.
5. If you really want to go commando on this, then you can do the whole thing manually. I'm not going to explain that here, but there is a good [LQ post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/mounting-an-iso-image-and-editing-it-463906/#post2333614) on how to do it.